# Calculate percent based on current time from two timestamp?

Tags: php

I try to get percent of two timestamps: `$startTime` and `$endTime` where:

`$startTime` is start date of event

`$endTime`   is end date

Need to calculate how time left from `$currentTime` to `$endTime` in percent.
For this I do:

```
function leftTimeCampaign($startTime, $endTime)
{
    $currentTime = time();

    if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
        return (100 * ($startTime - time())) / ($startTime - $endTime);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is your input and what is your current + expected output ?

Comment: Input is: leftTimeCampaign(`1426840989`, `1427445789`); Output should be number from 0 to 100(percent)

Comment: What is the problem? Apart from the fact that you are dividing two negative numbers - which seems a bit strange - this should work.

Comment: This link may helps to your problem http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Note that you call `time()` again where you probably meant to use `$currentTime`. Regardless, it's a bit backwards as jeroen said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(Current - Start) / (End - Start)
```

I suggest you use this value as-is (0..1 range) for further manipulations/storage and only multiply it by 100 when displaying.

I also advise that you don't simply return "0" if your preconditions are false.  More clearly, if `Start` > `End` then return a value outside of the value domain (e.g. -1) to signal an error, use other error reporting mechanisms (e.g. exceptions) or simply declare the case as undefined behavior (which is perfectly fine, just add an `assert()` call to make it clear).  If `Current` > `End`, you might want to return 1 as a special case depending on your scenario.

**Edit:** To get the relative amount of time *remaining*, simply take the opposite:

```
1 - (Current - Start) / (End - Start)
```

In percent:

```
100 * (1 - (Current - Start) / (End - Start))
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say, how much time gone, for this what change?

Comment: `1426723200`, `1426896000` it gives me left time `21.8% `

Comment: Considering the time you posted (approx 13:38:00 UTC, or 1426858680), that sounds about right. `100×(1−(1426858680−1426723200)÷(1426896000−1426723200)) = 21.597222222`. Did you expect a different result?

Comment: Yes, same result. Thanks for help

Comment: THANK YOU! This is fantastic.